# Specify a Java class literal programmatically (without hard coding it)? reflection?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, literals

### Questions:

1. In the line

   `Object o = myC.getConstructor(short.class).newInstance(myC.cast(pPrim));`

   Is there a way avoid hard coding "`short.class`" and instead get a literal from  `pPrim`?

   I got the idea for using "`short.class`" from the answer in [Create new object using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470263/create-new-object-using-reflection)
2. Shouldn't I be able to use "`T o = ...` (for a Byte or a Short, e.g.) instead of `Object o = ...`?

   I think my method is nearly identical to the one found at the end of [Class Literals as Runtime-Type Tokens](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html).
3. Is what I want to do a case of reflection?

### Background:

I'm studying the book OCA Java SE 7: Programmer 1 Study Guide by Finegan and Liguori in preparation for 1Z0-803.
So I'm practicing code a lot. While practicing, I wrote a class hoping to see what's going on
inside primitives when cast from a char. I listed the code below ... if you take a look please focus on the methods
byteToBinaryString, shortToBinaryString, and primitiveToBinaryString ... that's where my question arose.

### Steps that got me to the question:

2. wrote byteToBinaryString
3. cloned byteToBinaryString to shortToBinaryString
4. thought, "I should be able to avoid this method repitition, maybe with generics"
5. cloned shortToBinaryString to primitiveToBinaryString and tried to convert to generic
6. began thinking this was a reflection thing also
7. got stuck with the class literal hard coding

### Here's my code

```
    import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.Set;

public class StackoverflowQuestion {

  // I wrote this 1st
  public static String byteToBinaryString(byte pByte) {
    int primLength = 8;
    int count = 0;
    String s = "";
    while ( count++ < primLength ) {
      byte sm = (byte) (pByte & 0x01);
      pByte >>= 1;
      s = sm + s;
      if ( count % 4 == 0 && count != primLength ) {
        s = " " + s;
      }
    }
    return s;
  }

  // Then I cloned byteToBinaryString to this and had the thought, 
  // I shouldn' have to repeat this
  public static String shortToBinaryString(short pShort) {
    int primLength = 16;
    int count = 0;
    String s = "";
    while ( count++ < primLength ) {
      short sm = (short) (pShort & 0x0001);
      pShort >>= 1;
      s = sm + s;
      if ( count % 4 == 0 && count != primLength ) {
        s = " " + s;
      }
    }
    return s;
  }

  // So I cloned shortToBinaryString, modifidied to this and ...
  public static <T extends Number> String primitiveToBinaryString(T pPrim) {
    int primLength = 16;
    int count = 0;
    String className = pPrim.getClass().getName();
    try {
      Class<?> myC = Class.forName(className);
      // ... got stuck here
      Object o = myC.getConstructor(short.class).newInstance(myC.cast(pPrim));
      System.out.println(pPrim + "<--pPrim.equals(o)-->" + pPrim.equals(o) + "<--" + o);
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
      System.out.println("Caught exception: " + e);
    }
    String s = "";
    while ( count++ < primLength ) {
      //T sm = new Class<T>(pPrim.intValue() & 0x0001);
      //pPrim >>= 1;
      //s = sm + s;
      if ( count % 4 != 0 && count != primLength ) {
        s = "-" + s;
      }
    }
    return s;
  }

  public static void main ( String[] args ) {

    // exercise byteToBinaryString
    for ( int i = 0; i < 256; i++ ) {
      char cByte = (char) i; 
      byte b1 = (byte) cByte;
      System.out.printf( "char(%c): charValue(%05d): bin(%s): dec(%+6d)\n", cByte, (int) cByte, byteToBinaryString(b1), b1 );
    }

    // exercise shortToBinaryString
    // please ignore my use of TreeMap, just figuring out how it works
    TreeMap<Integer, String> charsTM = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
    charsTM.put(00000, "00000");
    charsTM.put(00001, "00001");
    charsTM.put(32766, "32766");
    charsTM.put(32767, "32767");
    charsTM.put(32768, "32768");
    charsTM.put(32769, "32769");
    charsTM.put(65535, "65535");

    short s1  = 32767;
    char  ch1 = 32768;

    Set<Integer> charKeys = charsTM.keySet();
    // loop through the boundary values I selected to show what's going on in memory
    for ( Integer i : charKeys ) {
      ch1 = (char) i.intValue();
      s1 = (short) ch1;
      System.out.printf( "char(%c): charValue(%05d): bin(%s): dec(%+6d)\n", ch1, (int) ch1, shortToBinaryString(s1), s1 );
    }

    // exercise primitiveToBinaryString
    primitiveToBinaryString( (byte)  127 );
    primitiveToBinaryString( (short) 32767 );
    primitiveToBinaryString( (int)   2147483647);
    primitiveToBinaryString(         2147483648L);
    primitiveToBinaryString(         2147483648F);
    primitiveToBinaryString(         2147483648D);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

This could be cleaned up a little:

```
String className = pPrim.getClass().getName();
Class<?> myC = Class.forName(className);
//Can just do
Class<?> myC = pPrim.getClass();
```

Also, if you are looking for a single argument constructor that takes a primitive value you could do:

```
public Constructor<?> getPrimitiveSingleArgConstructor(Class<?> myC) {

  for( Constructor<?> constructor : myC.getConstructors() ) {
    if( constructor.getParameterTypes().length == 1 ) {
      Class<?> paramType = constructor.getParameterTypes()[0];
      if (paramType.isPrimitive()) {
        return constructor;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, if you are trying to convert a number to an binary string and you are only working with integer numbers (I'm assuming you are) you could always cast the number upwards to a long and convert that to a binary string.

```
long integralValue = pPrim.longValue();
```

Comment: 1) Thanks for the clean up pointers. I always welcome them. 2) I tried your method `getPrimitiveSingleArgConstructor` in my code and it works. However, in the case of a `float` it loops through 3 constructors: `String`, `double`, and `float`. My code uses the `float` signature, but I haven't quite figured out why. 3) do you know whey I can only assign instance to a variable of type `Object o` instead of `T o`? 4) Prior to posting this question, the first thing I used was `Long.toBinaryString`, but I wanted to practice other coding skills ... that's why I my toBinary methods came in.

Comment: 2) Yes, if there are multiple single-arg primitive constructors that may cause trouble.  You could always use @Javier's approach to get the primitive class and look for a constructor with that class.  3) The getConstructor() method returns an array of Constructor<T> objects.  The getConstructors() method returns an array of Constructor<?> objects.  See the javadocs for explaination.  Since you have a Constructor<?> you can only instantiate Object.  You can cast it to a Constructor<T> and then instantitate T.

Comment: 5) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...) 
shows a return of a single Constructor<T>, and (on the same webpage) for getConstructors 
a return of Constructor<?>[] ... just want to make sure I'm looking at the correct things 6) the only cast
I can get to work is `Constructor<?> myConstructorQ = getPrimitiveSingleArgConstructor(myC); 
Constructor<T> myConstructorT = (Constructor<T>) myConstructorQ;`, but it produces an unchecked warning.
I can, however, now instantiate `T t`. Many thanks @Pace

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact, you can obtain a class literal from a primitive value by forcing a [boxing conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7), and then reflecting the static field `TYPE` (which is declared for any primitive wrapper).

```
 short s = 0;
 Object obj = s;
 System.out.println(obj.getClass().getDeclaredField("TYPE").get(null));
```

Here `obj.getClass()==Short.class`, and `Short.TYPE==short.class`. The assignment `obj=s` is a boxing conversion (from `short` to `Short`), followed by a reference widening conversion (from `Short` to `Object`). It also works if you replace the assignment by an invocation to a method such as `Object box(Object obj){return obj;}` because both assignment conversions and method invocation conversions allow boxing conversions to take place.

However, all of this reflection does not provide any advantage with respect to hardcoding `short.class`, since you can't have generics on primitive types.