# Android Room Database: How to handle Arraylist in an Entity?

Tags: java, android, android-room

I just implemented Room for offline data saving. But in an Entity class, I am getting the following error:

```
Error:(27, 30) error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
```

And the class is as following:

```
@Entity(tableName = "firstPageData")
public class MainActivityData {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String userId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "item1_id")
    private String itemOneId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "item2_id")
    private String itemTwoId;

    // THIS IS CAUSING THE ERROR... BASICALLY IT ISN'T READING ARRAYS
    @ColumnInfo(name = "mylist_array")
    private ArrayList<MyListItems> myListItems;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public ArrayList<MyListItems> getMyListItems() {
        return myListItems;
    }

    public void setCheckListItems(ArrayList<MyListItems> myListItems) {
        this.myListItems = myListItems;
    }

}
```

So basically I want to save the ArrayList in the database but I was not able to find anything relevant to it. Can you guide me regarding how to save an Array using Room?

NOTE: MyListItems Pojo class contains 2 Strings (as of now)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Option #1: Have `MyListItems` be an `@Entity`, as `MainActivityData` is. `MyListItems` would set up a `@ForeignKey` back to `MainActivityData`. In this case, though, `MainActivityData` cannot have `private ArrayList<MyListItems> myListItems`, as in Room, entities do not refer to other entities. A view model or similar POJO construct could have a `MainActivityData` and its associated `ArrayList<MyListItems>`, though.

Option #2: Set up a pair of `@TypeConverter` methods to convert `ArrayList<MyListItems>` to and from some basic type (e.g., a `String`, such as by using JSON as a storage format). Now, `MainActivityData` can have its `ArrayList<MyListItems>` directly. However, there will be no separate table for `MyListItems`, and so you cannot query on `MyListItems` very well.

Comment: @TusharGogna: Relationships are covered in [the Room documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html#entities-relationships), and the "entities do not refer directly to other entities" bit is also covered in [the Room documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html#no-object-references).

Comment: @CommonsWare is `Relation` an option #3 for this case? [Relation documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation.html)

Comment: @FeleMed: Not really. `@Relation` is only for getting things out of the database. It has nothing to do with putting things into the database.

Comment: Just as a note. If you're going to persist a list of Int for example, then you need to serialize it as string for option 2. This makes queries more complex. I would rather go for option 1 since is less "type" dependant.

Comment: You can read alternatives: https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-room-relationships-bf473510c14a

Comment: Sometime in the future you may need to query your Items so I'll usually go with option#1

Answer (score 170):

[Type Converter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/TypeConverter.html) are made specifically for that. In your case, you can use code snippet given below to store data in DB.

```
public class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    public static ArrayList<String> fromString(String value) {
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
        return new Gson().fromJson(value, listType);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromArrayList(ArrayList<String> list) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(list);
        return json;
    }
}
```

And mention this class in your Room DB like this

```
@Database (entities = {MainActivityData.class},version = 1)
@TypeConverters({Converters.class})
```

More info [here](http://thetechguru.in/storing-java-objects-primitive-types-room-database/)

Comment: Can anyone help me doing the same in Kotlin with List. In Java it was working fine. But when I converted it in Kolin its not working

Comment: How do you query from that arraylist?

Comment: @SanjogShrestha I don't understand  what do you mean. You just retrieve the arraylist and query using get method

Comment: @AmitBhandari Lets take the above scenario as an example. I want to search the table(MainActivityData) where myListItems contains (eg. a, b, c ) and userId is abc. Now how do we write query for such case?

Comment: @SanjogShrestha Query will remain same. Kind of like this, @Query("SELECT * FROM User")
    List<User> getUsers();

Comment: @SanjogShrestha You can put where clause as per your need. You can refer to link given in answer for more.

Comment: how this can be achieved using moshi?

Comment: How can we use these converters? What to write in code?

Comment: @CoolMind refer article provided in answer as a link for detailed use of this converter

Comment: @desgraci sorry, never used moshi

Comment: What the limit (max char) of my_list_array it also string field!!

Comment: @AshikAzeez Sorry, I have no idea, never looked into it.

Comment: Gson is an expensive object to recreate, so reuse your Gson instance as much as possible. Otherwise this is going to be very inefficient for large data sets.

Comment: @bompf thanks for the suggestion. Although this example here is just illustration. Generally we always keep one gson instance at application level.

Comment: How would you write a query to **add** an item to the list?

Comment: This should be selected as correct answer as it does not require to create another entity for simple list.

Comment: @AmitBhandari Link is not working anymore. Can you please either update the link or answer.

Comment: which class is "Type" can you provide the full import please?

Comment: Can you assist me with a type converter of List<HashMap<String, Object>> list;

Answer (score 78):

**Kotlin** version for type converter:

```
 class Converters {

    @TypeConverter
    fun listToJson(value: List<JobWorkHistory>?) = Gson().toJson(value)

    @TypeConverter
    fun jsonToList(value: String) = Gson().fromJson(value, Array<JobWorkHistory>::class.java).toList()
}
```

I Used `JobWorkHistory` object for my purpose, use the object of your own

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(JobDetailFile::class, JobResponse::class), version = 1)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class MyRoomDataBase : RoomDatabase() {
     abstract fun attachmentsDao(): AttachmentsDao
}
```

Comment: I think rather than deserializing to an array and then convert to List, it's better to use a List type like this: val listType = object : TypeToken<List<JobWorkHistory>>() {}.type like Amit mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: Also, You might want to fetch cached `Gson` instance from somewhere in your app. Initialising new `Gson` instance on every call can be expensive.

Answer (score 40):

**Native Kotlin version** using Kotlin's serialization component – *kotlinx.serialization*.

1. Add the Kotlin serialization Gradle plugin and dependency to your `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'

dependencies {
   ...
   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.0.1"
}
```

2. Add the Type converters to your Converter class;

```
class Converters {
   @TypeConverter
   fun fromList(value : List<String>) = Json.encodeToString(value)

   @TypeConverter
   fun toList(value: String) = Json.decodeFromString<List<String>>(value)
}
```

3. Add your Converter class to your database class:

```
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class YourDatabase: RoomDatabase() {...}
```

And you're done!

Extra resources:

- [Type Converters](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data#type-converters)
- [Kotlin Serialization](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/serialization.html)

Comment: if auto import not work add:

import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json

import kotlinx.serialization.decodeFromString

import kotlinx.serialization.encodeToString

Comment: You'll probably need `classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlinVersion")` as well

Answer (score 27):

Better version of `List<String>` converter

```
class StringListConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromString(stringListString: String): List<String> {
        return stringListString.split(",").map { it }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toString(stringList: List<String>): String {
        return stringList.joinToString(separator = ",")
    }
}
```

Comment: Be ware of using "," as separator as sometimes your string may have the same character and it can be a mess.

Answer (score 21):

**Kotlin Answer**

You need to do 3 things:

1. Create Converters class.
2. Add Converters class on Database.
3. Just define what you want to use in Entity class.

**Usage example step by step:**

Step 1 :

```
 class Converters {

    @TypeConverter
    fun listToJsonString(value: List<YourModel>?): String = Gson().toJson(value)

    @TypeConverter
    fun jsonStringToList(value: String) = Gson().fromJson(value, Array<YourModel>::class.java).toList()
}
```

Step 2 :

```
@Database(entities = [YourEntity::class], version = 1)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class YourDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
     abstract fun yourDao(): YourDao
}
```

Step 3 :

> Note: You do **not** need to call functions of Converter which are ***listToJsonString()*** and ***jsonStringToList()***. They are using in background by *Room*.

```
@Entity(tableName = "example_database_table") 
data class YourEntity(
  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Long = 0,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "your_model_list") var yourModelList: List<YourModel>,
)
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks @Caner

Answer (score 18):

I would personally advise against `@TypeConverters`/serializations, since they break the database's normal forms compliance.

For this particular case it might be worth [defining a relationship](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships) using the [@Relation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Relation) annotation, which allows to query nested entities into a single object without the added complexity of declaring a `@ForeignKey` and writing all the SQL queries manually:

```
@Entity
public class MainActivityData {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String userId;
    private String itemOneId;
    private String itemTwoId;
}

@Entity
public class MyListItem {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int id;
    public String ownerUserId;
    public String text;
}

/* This is the class we use to define our relationship,
   which will also be used to return our query results.
   Note that it is not defined as an @Entity */
public class DataWithItems {
    @Embedded public MainActivityData data;
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "userId"
        entityColumn = "ownerUserId"
    )
    public List<MyListItem> myListItems;
}

/* This is the DAO interface where we define the queries.
   Even though it looks like a single SELECT, Room performs
   two, therefore the @Transaction annotation is required */
@Dao
public interface ListItemsDao {
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM MainActivityData")
    public List<DataWithItems> getAllData();
}
```

Aside from this 1-N example, it is possible to define 1-1 and N-M relationships as well.

Comment: The only sane answer here! Don't violate First Normal Form!

Comment: I like this solution of using a 1 to N relationship. One question though, if you have a JSON file with some data and you want to store it in your DB, unlike the ArrayList approach which using Gson you can easily create instances of your object holding your data, how do you do it with this data structure?

Comment: @EmmanuelMurairi I'm afraid you can't. In order to instantiate arbitrary objects at runtime Gson uses [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10470279/12492043) -which you can use as well- but, as Room works on top of a relational database (SQLite), it structures the data into tables with predefined columns, so you need to know how the data is structured and declare the Entity classes in advance. When you use Gson you are just dumping a huge String into a single column and parsing it at runtime every time you read it. It's a nice workaround, but I try to avoid it as much as I can.

Comment: Sometimes you should, sometimes you shouldn't, depends on whether you need to manipulate it + use it in queries or not

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Of course, de-normalization some times can lead to a much better performance and many distributed systems take advantage of it. However, one should keep in mind that App requirements may change with newer versions (re-normalizing a de-normalized schema can be a real pain) and that type conversion is a manipulation on its own, which can drain resources (and battery) when not strictly necessary. Only de-normalize when you know what you're doing.

Comment: Yes, adding to above discussion: This is good for defined structures however, managing CURD operations are tricker and as mentioned, schema adjustments later on (if needed) are headaches.

Answer (score 11):

This is how i handle List conversion

```
public class GenreConverter {
@TypeConverter
public List<Integer> gettingListFromString(String genreIds) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] array = genreIds.split(",");

    for (String s : array) {
       if (!s.isEmpty()) {
           list.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
       }
    }
    return list;
}

@TypeConverter
public String writingStringFromList(List<Integer> list) {
    String genreIds = "";
    for (int i : list) {
        genreIds += "," + i;
    }
    return genreIds;
}}
```

And then on the database i do as shown below

```
@Database(entities = {MovieEntry.class}, version = 1)
@TypeConverters(GenreConverter.class)
```

And below is a kotlin implementation of the same;

```
class GenreConverter {
@TypeConverter
fun gettingListFromString(genreIds: String): List<Int> {
    val list = mutableListOf<Int>()

    val array = genreIds.split(",".toRegex()).dropLastWhile {
        it.isEmpty()
    }.toTypedArray()

    for (s in array) {
        if (s.isNotEmpty()) {
            list.add(s.toInt())
        }
    }
    return list
}

@TypeConverter
fun writingStringFromList(list: List<Int>): String {
    var genreIds=""
    for (i in list) genreIds += ",$i"
    return genreIds
}}
```

Comment: I use this solution for simple types (e.g. List<Integer>, List<Long>) because it is lighter than the gson-based solutions.

Comment: This solution miss the unhappy flow (e.g. null and empty String, null List).

Comment: Yeah I made the mistake of copy pasting this and lost at least an hour to single element lists creating elements with single commas. I have submitted and answer with a fix for that (in Kotlin)

Answer (score 6):

Had the same error message as described above.
I would like to add: if you get this error message in a @Query, you should add @TypeConverters above the @Query annotation.

Example:

```
@TypeConverters(DateConverter.class)
@Query("update myTable set myDate=:myDate  where id = :myId")
void updateStats(int myId, Date myDate);
```

....

```
public class DateConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    public static Date toDate(Long timestamp) {
        return timestamp == null ? null : new Date(timestamp);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Long toTimestamp(Date date) {
        return date == null ? null : date.getTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried adding  @TypeConverters above the Query annotation, but i am still getting the same error

Answer (score 4):

This answer uses Kotin to split by comma and construct the comma delineated string. The comma needs to go at the end of all but the last element, so this will handle single element lists as well.

```
object StringListConverter {
        @TypeConverter
        @JvmStatic
        fun toList(strings: String): List<String> {
            val list = mutableListOf<String>()
            val array = strings.split(",")
            for (s in array) {
                list.add(s)
            }
            return list
        }

        @TypeConverter
        @JvmStatic
        fun toString(strings: List<String>): String {
            var result = ""
            strings.forEachIndexed { index, element ->
                result += element
                if(index != (strings.size-1)){
                    result += ","
                }
            }
            return result
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

in my case problem was generic type
base on this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48480257/3675925
use List instead of ArrayList

```
 import androidx.room.TypeConverter
 import com.google.gson.Gson 
 import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
 class IntArrayListConverter {
     @TypeConverter
     fun fromString(value: String): List<Int> {
         val type = object: TypeToken<List<Int>>() {}.type
         return Gson().fromJson(value, type)
     }

     @TypeConverter
     fun fromArrayList(list: List<Int>): String {
         val type = object: TypeToken<List<Int>>() {}.type
         return Gson().toJson(list, type)
     } 
}
```

it doesn't need add @TypeConverters(IntArrayListConverter::class) to query in dao class nor fields in Entity class
and just add @TypeConverters(IntArrayListConverter::class) to database class

```
@Database(entities = [MyEntity::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(IntArrayListConverter::class)
abstract class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
```

Comment: This cant work because return type of {Gson().fromJson(arg1, arg2) } needs to return an arraylist of Strings not of Integers,.. {fromJson(arg1, arg2)} requires strings or typetokens

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to save and retrieve `String` list, then I think there is no need for JSON serialization.

Using built-in functions are much simpler and **you can avoid reflection too.**

Kotlin code:

```
class Converter {

    @TypeConverter
    fun List<String>.toStringData() = this.joinToString(STRING_SEPARATOR)

    @TypeConverter
    fun String.toList() = this.split(STRING_SEPARATOR)
}
```

Java code:

```
public class Converter {

    @TypeConverter
    public static String[] toArray(String data) {
        return data.split(STRING_SEPARATOR);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String toString(String[] data) {
        return String.join(STRING_SEPARATOR, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: You assume the strings don't include your STRING_SEPARATOR.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example for adding the customObject types to Room DB table.
https://mobikul.com/insert-custom-list-and-get-that-list-in-room-database-using-typeconverter/

Adding a type converter was easy, I just needed a method that could turn the list of objects into a string, and a method that could do the reverse. I used gson for this.

```
public class Converters {

    @TypeConverter
    public static String MyListItemListToString(List<MyListitem> list) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(list);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static List<Integer> stringToMyListItemList(@Nullable String data) {
        if (data == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<MyListItem>>() {}.getType();

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(data, listType);
    }
}
```

I then added an annotation to the field in the Entity:

```
@TypeConverters(Converters.class)

public final ArrayList<MyListItem> myListItems;
```

Answer (score 1):

When we are using TypeConverters then datatype should be return type of TypeConverter method.

For example: TypeConverter method returns a string, then adding table column should be of type string.

```
private static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        // Since we didn't alter the table, there's nothing else to do here.
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE "+  Collection.TABLE_STATUS  + " ADD COLUMN deviceType TEXT;");
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE "+  Collection.TABLE_STATUS  + " ADD COLUMN inboxType TEXT;");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

All above answers are for list of strings. But below helps you to write converter for list of objects.

Just in place of "**YourClassName**", add your Object class.

```
 @TypeConverter
        public String fromValuesToList(ArrayList<**YourClassName**> value) {
            if (value== null) {
                return (null);
            }
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<**YourClassName**>>() {}.getType();
            return gson.toJson(value, type);
        }
    
        @TypeConverter
        public ArrayList<**YourClassName**> toOptionValuesList(String value) {
            if (value== null) {
                return (null);
            }
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type type = new TypeToken<List<**YourClassName**>>() {
            }.getType();
            return gson.fromJson(value, type);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `@TypeConverters` with the converter class as params

to Database & to the Dao class, made my queries work

Comment: can you elaborate your answer ??

Answer (score 0):

Json conversions don't scale well in terms of memory allocation.I'd rather go for something similar to responses above with some nullability.

```
class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun stringAsStringList(strings: String?): List<String> {
        val list = mutableListOf<String>()
        strings
            ?.split(",")
            ?.forEach {
                list.add(it)
            }

        return list
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun stringListAsString(strings: List<String>?): String {
        var result = ""
        strings?.forEach { element ->
            result += "$element,"
        }
        return result.removeSuffix(",")
    }
}
```

For simple data types the above can be used, otherwise for complex datatypes Room provides [Embedded](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Embedded)

Comment: You assume the strings don't include ","

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM business_table")
 abstract List<DatabaseModels.Business> getBusinessInternal();


 @Transaction @Query("SELECT * FROM business_table")
 public ArrayList<DatabaseModels.Business> getBusiness(){
        return new ArrayList<>(getBusinessInternal());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers above correct. Yes, if you REALLY need store array of something into one SQLite field TypeConverter is a solution.

And I used the accepted answer in my projects.

But don't do it!!!

If you need store array in Entity in 90% cases you need to create one-to-many or many-to-many relationships.

Otherwise, your next SQL query for select something with key inside this array will be absolutely hell...

Example:

Object foo comes as json: [{id: 1, name: "abs"},  {id:2, name: "cde"}

Object bar: [{id, 1, foos: [1, 2], {...}]

So don't make entity like:

```
@Entity....
data class bar(
...
val foos: ArrayList<Int>)
```

Make like next:

```
@Entity(tablename="bar_foo", primaryKeys=["fooId", "barId"])
data class barFoo(val barId: Int, val fooId: Int)
```

And sore your foos:[] as records in this table.

Comment: dont make assumptions if yopu were storing a list of IDs that was available in the first api call but not in the next, then by all means store those ids somewhere and then use them to query the api store it into a table with a junction table, this uses both solutions, i do agree with you that this could be seen as an easy way out and isnt great for a lot of reasons

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to store a List containing photos URI in ROOM database . Because of special characters I was getting this error localized in my converter class, TypeConverters.class:

```
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated array at line 1 column 8 path $[1]
```

There was a problem in my simple converter for arrayList of String, in fact it was :

```
public static List<String> fromString(String value) {
    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {
    }.getType();
    return new Gson().fromJson(value, listType);
}

@TypeConverter
public static String fromArrayList(List<String> list) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(list);
}
```

By taking @Derrick Njeru comment back, I changed it for that it could take in consideration a String as "https://images.app.goo.gl/jwhkhzhZVWrceQV67" like this :

```
    @TypeConverter
public List<String> gettingListFromString(String genreIds) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] array = genreIds.split(",");
    
    for (String s : array) {
        if (!s.isEmpty()) {
            list.add(s);
        }
    }
    return list;
}

@TypeConverter
public String writingStringFromList(List<String> list) {
    String genreIds = "";
    for (String i : list) {
        genreIds += "," + i;
    }
    return genreIds;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use official solution from room, @Embedded annotation :

```
@Embedded(prefix = "mylist_array") private ArrayList<MyListItems> myListItems
```