# How to store a object array by using Room in Android?

Tags: android, arrays, android-room

I want to cache a song-list in my app, the Song-list structure is like below:

```
 @Entity
 public class Songlist {
      String _id;
      String desc;
      List<SongDesc> songWithComment;
      .....

    public static class SongDesc {
      String comment;
      Song song;
    }
}
 @Entity
 pulbic class Song {
      String name;
      String type;
      ......
 }
```

The lib of operating sqlite3 is [android.arch.persistence.room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html), but it dosen't allow object references in a table.Is there any way to cache a song-list by using Room in Android?

Comment: You would need separate `@Entity` classes that model the database structure (e.g., `SonglistEntity`, `SongEntity`), where the song has a `@ForeignKey` relationship back to the parent.

Comment: Thanks for reply! a song may include by countless songlist while a songlist contains limited songs, maybe I should use a `@ForeignKey` in `Songlist`? But I don't know how to deal with the list...

Answer (score 3):

Also if you want to store some custom objects, you can use @Embedded annotation like in example bellow :

```
class Address {
public String street;
public String state;
public String city;

@ColumnInfo(name = "post_code")
public int postCode; 
}


@Entity
class User {
@PrimaryKey
public int id;

public String firstName;

@Embedded
public Address address;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save an ArrayList of some type into the database, you shuld use `TypeConverter` to convert the ArrayList from and into a simpler recognizable type to the database engine, like a `String`.

See this:
[Android Room Database: How to handle Arraylist in an Entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44986626/android-room-database-how-to-handle-arraylist-in-an-entity)
and https://commonsware.com/AndroidArch/previews/room-and-custom-types

Comment: Your listed link specifically states that as the secondary option.

Comment: This is an option but your data won't be queryable.