# Query type-converted list of objects in Room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have a table that looks like following

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Product
{
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "ID")
    @JsonProperty("ID")
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Name")
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    public String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Documents")
    @JsonProperty("Documents")
    @TypeConverters(DocumentConverter.class)
    public List<Document> documents;
}
```

//...

```
@TypeConverters(DocumentConverter.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties( ignoreUnknown = true )
@JsonTypeName("Documents")
public class Document
{
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    public String name;

    @JsonProperty("URL")
    public String url;
}
```

I am able to retrieve a product based on its name by doing something like this

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE Name = :name")
List<Product> getProducts(String name);
```

And I would then be able to access the list of documents from each Product object. However I would also like to only deal with Products that has certain documents. I could get all Products via a query like above, then manually filter for the documents that I want, but it becomes quite a pain when I'm only looking for very specific documents.

Is it possible to also query based on Document variables without it being a separate table?

Something like...

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE Name = :name AND Document.name = :documentName")
List<Product> getProducts(String name, String documentName);
```

Thanks.

Comment: What about LEFT JOIN documents table? To make your question more clear and easy to understand and answer - show database structure for that two tables. How they referenced to each other. And tell if one document could be referenced by many products or not.

Comment: @AndreiVinogradov the two structure classes are at the top of the question. Can I provide more code to make the question better? The Document class isn't actually a separate table. In room you are able to convert a list of objects to a json object and store that as a column. 

My question was if it's possible to query this json object directly without storing Document as a separate table linked together with a foreign key. Currently I could retrieve the whole object and iterate over the sub list, although that is not very optimal.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LIKE sql statement to search inside your json column with converted documents list. Example:
Assume that we have document converted like this for storing in db:

```
{
    name: "Title",
    url: "Your_url"
}
```

So your query for product with such document in list should be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Product WHERE Name = :name AND Documents LIKE :documentLikeExpr
```

Where

```
String documentLikeExpr = "%name: \"Title\"%";
```

% in expression mean zero, one or multiple characters.

So the only thing we are doing here - is searching for part of string inside column using SQL language features.

Comment: Sounds like it might be easier to just have Document as a separate table bound together by a foreign key? This doesn't seem very optimal.

Comment: Exactly. This is not optimal, not fast enough. But you asked for a workaround without that - so this is an option you asked for. )

Answer (score 0):

You cannot query a Document class variables as it is not stored as a separate table. *@TypeConverter* annotation converts your Document list to some predefined data types such as String. Basically it stores list of Document as a string Gson in a column of Product table, So we cannot access the field *name* of Document class in SQL query like *Document.name*.

Read the Option #2 given by **@CommonsWare** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44986626/android-room-database-how-to-handle-arraylist-in-an-entity)

So, to access it you have to create a separate table for Document.