# Error while compution live data and IllegalStateException ROOM Database

Tags: java, android-studio, android-room

I need to use two arraylists in my database. Here is the entity class:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @NonNull
    public ArrayList<String> getValues(){
        return values;
    }

    @NonNull
    public ArrayList<String> getDates(){
        return dates;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getType_counter() {
        return type_counter;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getWhere_counter() {
        return where_counter;
    }

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "d")
    @TypeConverters({Converters.class})
    public ArrayList<String> dates;                   // arraylist here

    @ColumnInfo(name = "value")
    @TypeConverters({Converters.class})
    public ArrayList<String> values;                  // arraylist here

    @ColumnInfo(name = "type")
    public String type_counter;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "location")
    public String where_counter;
}
```

I have created a TypeConverter class as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44986626/android-room-database-how-to-handle-arraylist-in-an-entity) answer:

```
public class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    public static ArrayList<String> fromString(String value) {
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
        return new Gson().fromJson(value, listType);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromArrayList(ArrayList<String> list) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(list);
    }
}
```

I insert the values in the database this way:

```
private void saveNewValue(String value, String type, String location){

        // Getting current date
        Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        String formattedDate = df.format(c);

        //Saving new User
        userViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserViewModel.class);

        User user = new User();
        user.values.add(value);
        user.dates.add(formattedDate);
        user.type_counter = type;
        user.where_counter = location;

        userViewModel.insert(user);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I've got one activity with `RecyclerView` which has only type and location and when you click on a specific item you go to another activity where another `RecyclerView` shows all the values and dates  of this specific user (by id).

This is my DAO class:

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM User ")
    LiveData<List<User>> getAllValues();

    @Insert
    void insertValue(User ... users);

    @Delete
    void deleteValue(User user);

    @Query("SELECT location FROM User")
    LiveData<String[]> getAllLocations();

    @Query("SELECT * from User WHERE id=:id")
    LiveData<User> getUserWithId(int id);

}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: arch_disk_io_0
    Process: org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection, PID: 14774
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while computing database live data.
        at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:92)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:944)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:897)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:846)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.Converters.fromString(Converters.java:15)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.db.UserDao_Impl$3.call(UserDao_Impl.java:126)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.db.UserDao_Impl$3.call(UserDao_Impl.java:109)
        at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:90)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:351)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:80)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:932)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:897) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:846) 
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.Converters.fromString(Converters.java:15) 
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.db.UserDao_Impl$3.call(UserDao_Impl.java:126) 
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.db.UserDao_Impl$3.call(UserDao_Impl.java:109) 
        at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:90) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x72aa705400 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x72a70ea8e0
```

Could somebody please help me out? Thanks in advance.

I can provide extra info if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow you are storing data that does not contain the enclosing square brackets `[` and `]` around the list (in columns **d** and or **value**).

For example, the Type converter should convert that value fields/members to be along the lines of `["26-Jul-2022"]` or for multiple dates `["26-Jul-2022","25-Jul-2022"]`.

The Type Converter **`fromArrayList`** does this as it stands. The following based upon your code (first 5 rows) shows, using **App Inspection** that is the case:-

[image]

- rows with id's 6 and 7, as indicated by the crosses, lack the enclosing square brackets *(see the following for how this data replicates the failure you are encountering)*.

However, if the **`fromArrayList`** is modified to instead be :-

```
@TypeConverter
public static String fromArrayList(ArrayList<String> list) {
    Log.d("TYPCONVERTER","Type Converter >>fromArrayList<< invoked. ArrayList had " + list.size() + " elements.");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(list).replace("[","").replace("]","");
}
```

- i.e. it strips the '[' and ']'
- see rows 6 and 7

then running a test extraction, results in the exception that you are encountering (for the data):-

```
2022-07-26 10:27:15.328 28959-28959/a.a.so73110961javaroomlisttypeconverters E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: a.a.so73110961javaroomlisttypeconverters, PID: 28959
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{a.a.so73110961javaroomlisttypeconverters/a.a.so73110961javaroomlisttypeconverters.MainActivity}: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $
```

The fix is to ascertain where you are saving a string without the enclosing square brackets (and it is very unlikely the Type Converter)

Changing to use:-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM User " +
         "WHERE " +
         " substr(value,1,1) = '[' " +
         "AND substr(value,length(value),1) = ']'  " +
         "AND substr(d,1,1) = '[' " +
         "AND substr(d,length(d),1) = ']' " +
         "AND id=:id " +
         ";")
 LiveData<User> getValidUser(int id);
```

circumvents the failure BUT would return nothing for a User that has the incorrect data stored.

Using App Inspection you could run the following query to ascertain which rows would cause and issue :-

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE substr(d,1,1) <> '[' OR substr(d,length(d),1) <> ']' OR substr(value,1,1) <> '[' OR substr(value,length(value),1) <> ']';
```

e.g.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I did not know there is App Inspector! Makes it so much easier.