# Is there a way to save object references in an array list?

Tags: java

I'm coding a java program that allows you to "mix" drinks through the console. I have classes that inherit the drink class, and i want to for example create a new "beer" class if the user types the string "beer".
And a new "wine" class if the user types the string "wine".
How can I translate the "beer" string into the beer class.

I tried creating a ArrayList, then adding every class of drinks I have into it by saying

```
al.add(new Beer());
```

The problem is that I only want to create a new Instance of beer when the user actually types "beer".

Comment: You can create ArrayList of type "Beer" and can add Beer objects into the ArrayList. What other issue you face except this?

Comment: Do you want to create a new **class** Beer dynamically, or do you want to instantiate a new Beer object with new(). Those are two very different things, thus make sure your wording is precise!

Comment: Beyond that, I am not sure what you are asking for. Maybe add more code, including the part that gives you an error.

Comment: I want to instantiate a new Beer object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is to use a simple call to `Class#newInstance` method. Keep all classes in a structure and iterate over it to find the match.

An Example:

```
public class Classes {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<>();
        classes.add(Beer.class);
        classes.add(Wine.class);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine();

        for (Class<?> clazz : classes) {
            if (clazz.getSimpleName().equals(input)) {
                Object obj = clazz.newInstance();
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Beer {
        public Beer() {
            System.out.println("A beer has been created.");
        }
    }

    private static class Wine {
        public Wine() {
            System.out.println("A wine has been created.");
        }
    }
}
```

Input/Output example:

```
Wine
A wine has been created.
```

---

In case you have different constructors and you want to choose a different one each time, check this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470263/create-new-object-using-reflection)

Comment: Or a `Map<String, Supplier<Drink>> constructors = Map.of("Beer", Beer::new)`

Answer (score 0):

You cloud just check the user input in an if statement:

```
if (userInput.equals("beer")) {
   a1.add(new Beer());
}
```

Comment: I know, but i want to have a lot of drinks and I think hardcoding it isn't a nice solution.

Comment: @Slaw Yes that was another Idea I had. But even if I know that the String "beer" relates to an instance of the beer class, how can I instanciate another one?

Comment: Why do you need an instance of the beer class?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer I was searching for is called "reflection" in java.
Thanks guys!

Comment: Not really. Reflection is rarely the answer to anything in Java. It is extremely easy to get wrong, and you only notice at runtime. There are places where you need reflection, but again: it is an expert topic. You only use it if you absolutely have to. A person who didn't know about reflection an hour ago should not use it.