# Method to return different objects through casting

Tags: java, hibernate, casting

**What I expect to accomplish** (if its even possible):

I'm playing around with Hibernate and I just wanted to make a single class to handle simple CRUD of different objects / entities. I'm completely aware this might be bad practice but *it's just an experiment for learning purposes.*

**Brief example of what I'm trying to do**

```
public class TestFactory {

    private Class classType;
    private String configuration;

    public TestFactory(Class classType, String XML) {
        this.classType = classType;
        this.configuration = configurationName(XML);
    }

    private SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return new Configuration()
                .configure(this.configuration)
                .addAnnotatedClass(this.classType)
                .buildSessionFactory();
    }

    public <T> T get(int id) {

        try (SessionFactory factory = getSessionFactory();
             Session session = factory.getCurrentSession()) {
            session.beginTransaction();

            // Attempting to cast the result to the class required
            T object = this.classType.cast(session.get(this.classType, id));

            session.getTransaction().commit();
            return object;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected usage**

```
TestFactory factory = new TestFactory(JustSample.class, "A-conf.xml")

// Should return the object casted to a JustSample class
JustSample sample = factory.get(5);

TestFactory factory = new TestFactory(AnotherSample.class, "B-conf.xml")

// Should return the object casted to a AnotherSample class
AnotherSample another = factory.get(5);
```

So my idea is to pass any Class.class and have the factory do everything else, this is just an experiment that came to my mind.

Is it possible to do such casting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create new object using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470263/create-new-object-using-reflection)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thank you, sorry it took me awhile to understand it, but what do I do if I specifically need to use casting? is it possible?

Comment: Is your question "Why casting does not convert result `new SomeType1()` to `SomeUnrelatedType`?" Very unclear where do you want to use casting...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I should have explained myself better since the beginning, do you mind taking another look at my post please?

Comment: Jouo that's very different (and better looking) question compared to how it was written before. Enrico's answer (essentially `Class<T> clazz;`) seem to be the answer... unless you are looking for something else...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Oh true! thank you, I simply set the Method's return type to T, and casted the session.get using (T)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, not sure if it's exactly what you are looking for.

```
public class SimpleClass<T> {
    private final Class<T> clazz;

    SimpleClass(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public T getObject() throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        // Should return a new object based on the class type
        return clazz.newInstance();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and sorry for wasting your time, do you mind taking a look at my edited post where I clarified my issue a bit better?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class Test {

    public static <T> Object foo(Class c) {
        Object ob = null;
        try {
            ob = c.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ob;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(foo(Sample1.class));
        System.out.println(foo(Sample2.class));
    }
}

class Sample1 {

}

class Sample2 {

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and sorry for wasting your time, do you mind taking a look at my edited post where I clarified my issue a bit better?